# How to change AviSynth plugins directory?

Tags: plugins, script

I installed anew version of `AviSynth+` and besides solving some problems with its `DirectShowSource.dll` I discover (from the `Setup Log` file) that it consider `C:\` as its autoload directory.

It helped me - I copied `DLLs` there. But it is neither elegant nor useful solution (as I have installed both 32- and 64-bit versions).

How to change configuration to return to default `plugins+` and `plugins64+` directories?

Comment: Consult the [docs](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/AviSynth%2B#AviSynth.2B.27s_Plugin_Autoloader).

Comment: @Mulvya: Thank your for your valuable advice. I followed your link and created appropriate registry keys and for 32-bit **it works**! - If you will write it in the form of an answer, I will accept and upvote it.

Comment: @Mulvya: Do you know, please, what to do with 64-bits plugins? I tried guess the name of the key from 32-bit version name( `PluginDir+`), e. g. `PluginDir64+`, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs indicate, you have to create registry keys to tell Avisynth+ where to look. They are

```
PluginDir+ in Software/Avisynth in HKEY_CURRENT_USER
PluginDir+ in Software/Avisynth in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
PluginDir2_5 in Software/Avisynth in HKEY_CURRENT_USER
PluginDir2_5 in Software/Avisynth in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

There is no separate key for 32 or 64-bit. Since 32-bit AVS will not load 64-bit plugins, I suggest setting the first key in the above list to the 64-bit plugins folder, and the 2nd to the 32-bit. The 64-bit AVS DLL when loaded will use plugins from the first folder. The 32-bit DLL will skip them and load from the 2nd folder.

Comment: Thank you again - now **both** `64-bit` and `32-bit` autoload directories are recognized by `AviSynth+', so **all things work**.